# Confusion of slug with route part "new" etc

Tags: symfony-1.4, url-routing, doctrine-1.2, slug

I have a sfDoctrineRouteCollection:

```
foo:
  class:  sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model: Foo
    columns: slug
    action: [list, show, new, create, edit, update, delete]
```

If someone now creates a new entity whose slug results in, for example, "new", the routing engine gets confused regarding the two routes `/foo/new` for creating new entities and `/foo/new` for showing the entity with slug "new".

What's a clean and elegant solution to this problem?

Of course, I could provide explicit route definitions, but that would make sfDoctrineRouteCollection kind of obsolete. A separate route definition for the "show" action would already solve the problem, for example, by adding a prefix like "/foo/:slug/show". I also could provide a custom slugify method intercepting slugs like "new" etc.

Do you know any clean and elegant solutions?

Comment: Would it help to either use the prefix_path or segment_name option as shown here: http://www.symfonyreference.com/routing-yml?

Comment: Well, if you have an item with a slug `new` and you want to see it, it will goes to `/foo/new/show`, `/foo/new` shouldn't display anything, because it doesn't know what to do.. The action parameter isn't present. Otherwise, you should avoid `slug` to be `new`, or whatever actions that can break the route.

Comment: @j0k "the action" is implicit in this case. Symfony uses the request method to find the correct action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`segment_names`](http://www.symfonyreference.com/routing-yml#segment-names-366) option to change `new` to something else or you can use something more explicit like `id` or `id-slug` or disable [`with_show`](http://www.symfonyreference.com/routing-yml#with-show-365) and add a show [object action](http://www.symfonyreference.com/routing-yml#object-actions-380)

`object_actions: { show: [get, head] }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `segment_names` wouldn't do the trick because corresponding names could also be used for creating a new object. Disabling the standard show action and defining an additional object action is nearly the same as providing an explicit route definition (as I mentioned in my question). Extending the slug wouldn't also solve the problem completely. For sure, it would be challenging to create a new object with a matching slug also containing the id. But this is not an option at all because that's one of the reasons for using a slug: Removing ids from the URL. (IMHO)

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for your answer. I think I will define an explicit show action like `/foo/:slug/show`.